# Proof that a set $A$ is nowhere dense set in $R$ if and only if every sphere $S \subset R$ contains another set $S'$ such that $S' \cap A = \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am having problems trying to understand and prove this assertion. For instance to prove the first part:

Let $A$ be a nowhere dense set and let $S$ be any set in $R$. Then if $A \cap S = \emptyset$ of course any set $S' \subset S$ has an empty intersection with $A$. Now suppose $A \cap S \neq \emptyset$. This implies that $S - A \neq \emptyset$ or $S=A$. If it is the first case, just let $S' = S - A$ and it follows that $S' \cap A = \emptyset$. Finally if $S=A$ then select $S' = \emptyset$ (which is a subset of every set) and thus again $S' \cap A = \emptyset$.

What is wrong with this line of reasoning? And if nothing is wrong, it seems to me that we don't require $A$ to be a nowhere dense set. Could you provide a proof and/or comment on this one?

Thanks a lot and happy saturday!

Comment: Incidentally, any $S$ contains $S':=\emptyset $ as subset. -- Also, if your $R$ is supposed to be $\Bbb R$, then a speher is simply a two-element set. I suspect that you misquoted the problem statement

Comment: Sir, here $R$ refers to any metric space in general.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely assumes you are not allowed to take $S'= \emptyset$. 
Following what you write, observe that $S=A \implies \exists$ a point in the interior of $A$ (which follows directly from the fact that $S$ is a sphere) which isn't allowed since $A$ is nowhere dense set.

Comment: So in essence, we do not allow the case of $S \neq A$ because this contradicts the assumption that $A$ is a nowhere dense set? And this completes the first part of the proof (?)

Comment: That is correct.